# Identifying navigate types in react navigation navigationRef

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add types to my TS version of this function, and am having a bit of trouble.

From the [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/):

```
// RootNavigation.js

import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef<RootStackParamList>()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```

I am using Typescript and want to add types to the params `navigate(name, params)` but I can't quite figure out what they should be. Any thoughts?

I already have the container typed like so:

`export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef<RootStackParamList>()`

Comment: in my project i use `navigate = (name: string, params?: any)`

Comment: @paperskyline ideally the types would not allow for any non-real paths to be entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `navigate` like this

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import {createNavigationContainerRef} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {RootStackParamList} from './RootStackParamList';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef<RootStackParamList>();

export function navigate<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
  ...args: RouteName extends unknown
    ? undefined extends RootStackParamList[RouteName]
      ?
          | [screen: RouteName]
          | [screen: RouteName, params: RootStackParamList[RouteName]]
      : [screen: RouteName, params: RootStackParamList[RouteName]]
    : never
) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(...args);
  }
}
```